# Trying to parse a custom log using grok

Tags: parsing, logging, logstash, logstash-grok, grok

I have the following log:

```
2016-10-20T23:56:42.000+00:00 clientIp:83.149.9.216 TransactionId=1233 TransactionType=Sell
```

How can i ignore the words clientIp:, TransactionId= and TransactionType= to match only the values?

If I modify my log to look like this:

```
2016-10-20T23:56:42.000+00:00 83.149.9.216 1233 Sell
```

And I use this pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{IP:clientIp} %{NUMBER:TransactionId} %{WORD:TransactionType}
```

It works.
So i need a way to read only the values after "word:" or "word="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern can include literals, e.g.

```
 TransactionId=%{NUMBER:TransactionId}
```